# Stopwatch not working, it's going way too faster

Tags: javascript

As I was looking for a simple Stopwatch implementation in JS, I found this code http://codepen.io/_Billy_Brown/pen/dbJeh/
The problem is that it's not working fine, the clock go way too fast. I got 30 seconds on the screen when i got only 23 seconds on my watch.
And I don't understand why. The timer function is called every millisecond and should be updating the time correctly.

```
setInterval(this.timer, 1);
```

Is the problem coming from the browser or from the JS code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In fact the code you gave is imitating time flow, but it is not synchronized with system time.

Every millisecond it just invokes the function `this.time`, which performs recounting of millis, seconds and so on
without getting native system time, but just adding 1 to variable representing "imaginary milliseconds".
So we can say that resulting pseudo-time you see depends on your CPU, browser and who knows what else.

On our modern fantastically fast computers the body of `this.time` function is being executed faster than millisecond (wondering what would happen on Pentium 2 with IE5 on board).
Anyhow there is no chance for the `this.time` to be executed exactly in particular fixed period on all computers and browsers.

The simplest correct way to show the time passed since startpoint according to the system time is:

```html
<body>
<script>
var startTime = new Date() // assume this initialization to be start point

function getTimeSinceStart()
{
  var millisSinceStart = new Date() - startTime
    , millis = millisSinceStart % 1000
    , seconds = Math.floor(millisSinceStart / 1000)

  return [seconds, millis].join( ':' )
}

(function loop()
{
  document.title = getTimeSinceStart() // look on the top of page

  setTimeout( loop, 10 )
}())
</script>
</body>
```

P.S. What @Guffa says in his answer is correct (generally for js in browsers), but in this case it does not matter and not affect the problem

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't matter and not affect the problem?

Comment: @Guffa, the key phrase is "**in this case**". My answer explains why even if we had multythreaded js the problem remains.

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't matter in this case? If you try to run an interval every millisecond and the minimum time for intervals doesn't let you do that, it will definitely matter.

Answer (score 1):

The timers in Javascript doesn't have millisecond precision.

There is a minimum time for the interval, which differs depending on the browser and browser version. Typical minimums are 4 ms for recent browsers and 10 ms for a little older browsers.

Also, you can't rely on the callback being called at exact the time that you specify. Javascript is single threaded, which means that if some other code is running when the timer triggers a tick, it has to wait until that other code finishes.